# android tablet icon sizes

Tags: android

I have created four versions of my launcher icon for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi devices. They are of dimensions 36x36, 48x48, 72x72 and 96x96.

I'm wondering what will happen when using a large screen. Consdering large screens are rouglhy 7" + in size a ldpi, large screen will surely not want a 32x32 icon image, located in a drawable-ldpi folder.

I cannot find anything on the dev guide that indicates what icon sizes to assign to large and xlarge devices. Presumably I would put a larger copy of the icon in the `drawable-large` and `drawable-xlarge` folder. However, I do not know what sizes to use. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 7-10" tablet doesn't need anything unusually large. You don't need anything bigger than a 96x96 launcher icon for this use case. There is [a table in the Launcher Icons section](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html) of the design docs that shows which sizes correspond to which densities.

Have a look at the [Declaring Tablet Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) section of the design docs for more info on  how to organize resources for 7-10" screens. (Note that the resource used will depend on the screen density, it is possible that a 7" tablet will have an mdpi screen.)

Comment: So it would be fine to place a 96x96 version of my icon in drawable-large and xlarge? Else how with a large ldpi device know to use the 96x96 icon from the `drawable-xhdpi` folder

Comment: A physically large ldpi screen is still only going to be about 480x854 pixels (see the tablet layout guidelines I linked you too), so it wouldn't want to use the 96x96 pixel icon. Android will pick the appropriate resource for the size and density. All you have to do put said resources in the right folders.

Answer (score 7):

Google provide an online tool called Android Assest Studio which creates the launcher icons in the correct size for you. http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-launcher.html

Comment: Useful tool, thanks. But I don't think this answers the question. I already have my icon images

Comment: To create alternative bitmap drawables for different densities, you should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized densities. For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen (the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes should be:

36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html